# Concatenating strings in arguments (php)

Tags: php, string, wordpress, string-concatenation

In Flash (AS2) you can add strings like so:

```
variable = "a"+"b"
```

and the result will be a a string with the value of "ab".

I understand this (concatenation of strings) is done with the "." operator in php, but I'm wondering whether it's possible to do this when you pass an argument?

Specifically, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
$o = get_post_meta($id, 'locationForDay'.$i, true);
```

Where "get_post_meta" is a wordpress function for getting custom data attached to a blog post. (I'm trying to fetch a bunch of variables called 'locationForDay1", "...2" and so on in a loop)

(I have tried it out and got an error, but I'm not sure whether it's based on this or other mistakes in my amateur-ish php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your following statement will work fine:

```
$o = get_post_meta($id, 'locationForDay'.$i, true);
```

Although, if you are unsure you can always throw parenthesis around a string:

```
$o = get_post_meta($id, ('locationForDay'.$i), true);
```

**Edit:** It should be worth noting that it is possible to concatenate strings using a comma (,). Therefore the following statement would **NOT** work:

```
$o = get_post_meta($id, 'locationForDay',$i, true);
```

Whereas, the above statement would call the function `get_post_meta` and contain 4 arguments. In this instance it would be crucial to include the parenthesis in order to achieve your string concatenation:

```
$o = get_post_meta($id, ('locationForDay',$i), true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$o = get_post_meta($id, ('locationForDay'.$i), true);
```

or

```
$o = get_post_meta($id, ('locationForDay'.$i.''), true);
```

or

```
$o = get_post_meta($id, ('locationForDay',$i,''), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can concat variables as they are being passed into a function like that.